# Get url parameter in cakephp 1.2.4.8284

Tags: php, cakephp, url-routing

I am using cake php version 1.2.4.8284

I have url like below

```
http://www.example.com/users/index/filter:/site:917+919/
```

But when i print this url in users controller with `'print_r($this->params);'`

I get result like below.

```
Array
(
    [pass] => Array
        (
        )

    [named] => Array
        (
            [filter] => 
            [site] => 917 919
        )

    [controller] => users
    [action] => index
    [plugin] => 
    [url] => Array
        (
            [ext] => html
            [url] => users/index/filter:/site:917 919/
        )

    [form] => Array
        (
        )

    [isAjax] => 
)
```

Here you can see + is missing from 'site' and 'url'.

But I want exact url and site value. Please Help.

Comment: I didn't know the cakephp has version `1.2.4.8284`. Can you double check the cakephp version number?

Comment: Yes, that is very old version

Answer (score 1):

Your URL must be encoded to get the actual symbol.

```
http:www.example.com/users/index/filter:/site:917%2B919/
```

Answer (score 1):

The `+` character represents a space in a URL so `print_r($this->params)` is returning the correct value. If you want your url to include an actual `+` character you need to URL encode it as `%2B`; so your URL would be:-

> http:www.example.com/users/index/filter:/site:917%2B919/

You might want to take a look at the PHP docs about [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).